# 会计 instead of <美>收银机，现金出纳机, cash register?

Tags: vocabulary

[Bentley Little, The Summoning](http://www.my285.com/wgwx/cxs/btl/my/002.htm) has 会计 for original's "cash register":

> 苏·温不声不响地站在餐馆会计的后面，越过会计的头顶，她看了看餐馆里仅有的两位客人，他又从会计的头顶上方斜了他们一眼，苏从会计那儿绕出来，走到他们的桌子前，回到会计那里后，苏又继续折叠那些菜单

On the other hand 会计 is universally translated as "accountant" see e.g. Baidu.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, 会计 refers to the person who is doing the accounting job, that is, **accountant**.

Most of time, 会计 just refers to **accountant**, as in: 她是个会计.

会计 can also refer to the job for **accounting**, as in 会计学，会计师，会计协会，etc.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the English text. From the Chinese context, "会计" here refers to the cashier (the person), not the cash register (the machine).

As a native Chinese speaker, the first word came to my head for the cashier is "收银员". "会计" is not used for this job.

However, I don't think everyone knows the difference. The vague idea for "会计" for many people might be "the person dealing with money in an organization/company/...". A cashier deals with money, so he is a "会计".

For cash register, try "收银机". But this word is not often here. We often use "收款台" to refer to where you pay, which means cash counter.

Comment: original：苏·温不声不响地站在餐馆会计的后面，Sue Wing tried to be as unobtrusive as possible as she stood behind the restaurant's **cash register** 越过会计的头顶，她看了看餐馆里仅有的两位客人，she glanced over the top of the **cash register** at the restaurant's lone customers, 他又从会计的头顶上方斜了他们一眼，she peeked at them over the top of the **register** 苏从会计那儿绕出来，Sue stepped around the **register** 走到他们的桌子前，回到会计那里后，moving back behind the **register** 苏又继续折叠那些菜单

Comment: Then that would be 收款台/收银台。Although it not cash register, it is what we usually use. "会计" is a person.

Comment: @user6065, I don't think the original translation you post here is correct. No native speaker would understand 会计 in those sentences as **cash register**, but a person dealing with accounting.

Comment: maybe used as code for cash register, context makes intended meaning obvious, translator also seems not familiar with US environment, e.g. US person would know that "Dr. Pepper" in the given context refers to a soft drink, not so translator,  cf.冲进了厨房找水喝,heading into the kitchen to get something to drink, 一会儿, 弟弟从厨房里走了出来，手里拿着派泊博士的书 he came back a moment later, Dr. Pepper in hand,

Comment: Native speakers might prefer 柜台，前台，收银台 to 会计

Comment: Sue Wing also seems to become a man somewhere between the first and the second sentences in the Chinese translation, and to me it feels like there’s significant overuse of pronouns overall. Doesn’t seem to be a particularly good translation based on this snippet.